# How can I crop images(barcode) taken by hands, using Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, crop, pseudocode

Let's say I have 2 pictures of barcode.

[image: Barcode1]
[image: Barcode2]

Since these are photographs taken by hand, I need to crop these images before I make into dataset.

What I want to do is, crop the barcode image part. So that I get like the following,

[image: Barcode3]

Actually, I totally have no idea where to start!

Find the white part from all four corners? Or find the center point of the barcode part? Or rotating the picture would be the starting point?

Any, if any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Python or Tensorflow is what I'm going to use, but any pseudo-code will be welcome!

Comment: I do not know if this will solve your problem but there is a python module pyzbar that  appears to be able  to read bar code images and define a bounding box for the code. Documentation is at https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/

Comment: There is also  a tutorial at https://techtutorialsx.com/2020/01/01/python-pyzbar-detecting-and-decoding-barcode/ which discusses issues of bounding boxes, and rotation

Comment: @GerryP I think this module is the one I'm looking for. I'll figure it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tutorial on bar code detection using python and opencv is explained [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/15/real-time-barcode-detection-video-python-opencv/). Thanks!